# Ошибка в программе "Степень симметрии"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char a[255];
    cin >> a;

    int len = strlen(a);

    int s = 0,count = 0;
    while(true){
        if(a[len/2-s-1]==a[len/2+s]){
            count++;
            s++;
        } else break;
    }

    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> **Степень симметрии**
>
> Степенью симметрии натурального числа назовём количество пар его
>   десятичных цифр, в которых цифры совпадают и расположены симметрично
>   относительно середины десятичной записи этого числа. Если некоторая
>   цифра стоит посередине десятичной записи, её тоже нужно учитывать в
>   паре с ней самой. Найти степень симметрии числа n.
>
> *Входные данные*
>
> Одно натуральное число `n (n < 2 ·10^9)`.
>
> *Выходные данные*
>
> Вывести степень симметрии числа `n`.
>   В результате три правильных ответа из 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный цикл

```
while(true){
    if(a[len/2-s-1]==a[len/2+s]){
        count++;
        s++;
    } else break;
}
```

приводит к неопределенному поведению программы, так как в нем нет проверки, произошел ли выход за пределы массива или нет.

Кроме того если число содержит нечетное число цифр, как, например, `12321`, то

```
Len / 2
```

будет равно 2. В результате при первой итерации цикла вы сравниваете элементы в позициях 1 (`len/2-s-1`) и 2 (`len/2+s`), которые соответствуют цифрам 2 т 3, и получается неверный итог.

Comment: Да, действительно, я не учел вариант с непарным кол-вом цифр.